# ¿Cómo puedo volver a una página de partida variable desde un de destino?

Tags: angular, angular5

Tengo un página de ayuda, accesible desde varias páginas, con enlaces, a su vez, a varias páginas de ayuda más especificas. Estas últimas tienen un botón para retornar a la de ayuda principal, aquí sin problema. La página de ayuda a su vez tiene un botón para volver a la página desde donde se invoco (la primera vez) que es lo que necesito que funcione.
Es decir que hay páginas generales como: eventos, usuarios, localizaciones, documentos... y desde cada una de estas páginas se puede acceder a la página de ayuda. Por lo que se debería volver a la página concreta donde se estaba una vez consultada la ayuda.

Inicialmente invocaba a un método que llame `goBack()` al hacer clic en el botón de volver. En este método tenía un objeto de *Location* con una llamada a *back()*: `location.back()`. Esto funciona bien si sólo se abre la página de ayuda y seguidamente se pulsa el botón, pero si se accede a alguna de las paginas enlazadas en la de ayuda, entra en bucle, porque al volver a la principal de ayuda si pulsas el botón de "atras" con la implementación que tenía vuelves nuevamente a la página de ayuda específica previamente visitada.

Soy nuevo en Angular y no se si hay alguna forma de hacer esto directamente o se requieren alternativas. Se me ha ocurrido por ejemplo, guardar la URI en ***session storage*** si no esta seteada al pulsar el botón de acceso a la ayuda, y borrarla cuando se invoque a *goBack()* desde esta. Pero no se si es la opción correcta.

Comment: usar sessionStorage o localStorage es una solución perfectamente válida para tu problema puntual, pero a la larga, si quieres manejar distintos estados y propagarlos a todos los componentes, eventualmente tendrás que aprender a usar una librería de manejo de estados. [ngrx](https://medium.com/@nomanbinhussein/getting-started-with-ngrx-5cec2788b25f) es la librería "nativa" de angular para manejo de estados. Básicamente desde un componente puedes cambiar el estado de una variable, y todos los componentes suscritos a ella reaccionan. En este, caso, cambiando el link donde deben volver

Comment: @amenadiel gracias, en cuanto tenga un rato lo miro